# Close vote queue, flagged as showing "subreason.InputTitle"

Tags: bug, review-queues, vote-to-close, post-notice

I was doing some reviews in the [Close votes queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/28394084) and noticed that the [UI had changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues?page=3&tab=oldest#tab-top), with the Actions now to the right as a radio combination rather than buttons, all fine and good.

However, the flagging dialog looks like it might have a slight bug highlighted below as it is showing `subreason.InputTitle` as part of the text.

> This question has been flagged as:
> Not suitable for this site: This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline.
> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center. (1)
> **subreason.InputTitle**: This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers. (1)
> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network (1)

[image: Close Votes queue post notice]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Also reported on [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361339/289905).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been reported on the Visual design changes to the review queues https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361339/289905